# Wait for a recursive jQuery function to completely finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

Another one that should be simple, but is giving me trouble. I am trying to learn about jQuery's .Deferred() and .promise() functionality to delay certain actions until a recursive function is completely finished. Currently, my code is similar to the following:

```
    function showText(setTarget, setMessage, setIndex, setInterval) {
        var defer = jQuery.Deferred();
        var doShowText = function (target, message, index, interval) {
            if (index < message.length) {
                $(target).append(message[index++]);
                setTimeout(function () { doShowText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
            }
            else {
                alert("Done!");
                defer.resolve();
            }
        };

        doShowText(setTarget, setMessage, setIndex, setInterval);
        return defer.promise();
    }

function startButtonClick() {
    displayElement($("#getElement"));
    showText($("#getElement > h1"), "This text will slowly write to the screen.", 0, 50).promise()
        .then(alert("Finished."));

}
```

When this runs, "Finished" alert (which I am trying to defer) runs after the first execution of the recursive script, so it will appear when only one letter has been printed (not the intended result). The "Done" alert, however, appears correctly once all of the letters have been printed and the recursion is finished, so it seems as though my defer variable should not be resolved until then. Can anyone help me discover why the "Finished" alert is being called early here? Any assistance is appreciated!

EDIT: I realized I had accidentally posted a slightly older version of my code. It has been updated with the correct version (the behavior at run time is the same).

Comment: Thank you so much to both who answered! Putting the alert into a function fixed it. =) Marked plalx as correct since his came first but both answers are correct, and I removed the extra 'promise()'. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happening because you are actually executing the `alert` function right away instead of passing a function reference.

Do this instead:

```
.then(alert.bind(null, 'finished'));
```

Or

```
.then(function () {
    alert('finished');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `startButtonClick` function you don't need to call `.promise()` on the result of `showText`, because you are already doing that inside of `showText`. Next, the argument to the `then` callback should be a function, right now you are immediately calling the alert function, not passing it as a function, which is why it is displaying immediately, so just wrap it in a function:

```
function(){ alert("Finished."); }
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/RnLXF/

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a fiddle with the whole lot wrapped up in a nice little object:** http://jsfiddle.net/YVZKw/3/

As *plalx* and *ctcherry* have already stated, the biggest problem was the lack of a function in your .then call.

**HTML**

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)'>Start</a>

<div id='sampleElement'>
    <h1></h1>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('a').on('click', function(){

    new ShowText(
        $("#sampleElement > h1"), 
        "I will slowly write text to the screen.",
        50
    )
    .done(function(){
        alert("Finished.")
    });
});

function ShowText(target, message, speed)
{
    me = this;
    me.target = target;
    me.message = message;
    me.index = 0;
    me.speed = speed;
    me.defer = new $.Deferred();

    me.interval = setInterval(function() {
        me.target.append(me.message[me.index++]);
        if (me.index > me.message.length) {
            clearInterval(me.interval);
            me.defer.resolve();
        }
    }, me.speed);

    return me.defer;
}
```